# Почему websocket перестал работать на порте после обновления php?

Tags: php, apache, websocket, symfony3, ratchet

OS: macOS High Siera
Web сервер: apache 2.4, php7.1
Фреймворк: Symfony3
Сокет запущен на Ratchet

После установки APCu и OPcache перестал работать websocket.
Консоль после запуска `php bin/console sockets:start` никаких ошибок не отдает.
До этого он не хотел запускаться, почему-то стал жаловаться на xdebug, я его удалил.
Но браузер не может подсоединиться
[image: ошибка]
В чем может быть проблема? И как её устранить?

Comment: Смотрите логи PHP

Comment: @DanielProtopopov смотрел логи error apache но там ничего. Какие именно?